# Azure Devops Advance Security not detecting latest vulnerabilities

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, security-code-scan

I have a C# Web-Api project with a vulnerability.

System.Data.SqlClient version 4.8.5

I can also see this vulnerability in https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-98g6-xh36-x2p7.

When I execute the Azure DevOps Advanced Security scan, I can see other vulnerabilities in the report, but not the one mentioned above

I tried changing the code , deliberately added new vulnerability just ensure the the scan is not getting cached , but to no avail.

Could you please help me understand why I'm not seeing this particular vulnerability?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tested to add the package: System.Data.SqlClient version 4.8.5 to project and use the task: `AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1` to detect the vulnerabilities.

It can show the latest detecting latest vulnerability of the System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.5.

Here is an example:

Add the package to the project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.SignalR" Version="1.18.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient " Version="4.8.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Pipeline Result:

[image]

You can check the following points:

1.You can check if the correct version of the Nuget Package has been restored at the Nuget Restore step.

For example:

[image]

2.Refer to this ticket: [Advanced Security isn't using the latest advisories](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Advanced-Security-isnt-using-the-latest/10508676?sort=newest)

> The trigger to submit a new artifact to our service is when there’s a new commit. Even if the component was found before, if a new vulnerability/CVE is identified, a new scan with a new commit must be submitted.

You can try to add a new commit to the branch being scanned in the repo and then you can run the Dependency Scanning again to check if it can get the latest vulnerabilities.

Comment: we tried all the options , but to no avail.
But this morning all of sudden we are seeing the vulnerabilities in Advance Security Dashboard today morning- its like some cache go cleaned on Advance Security end.
we didn't do any changes.